# Any limitation about the size of grid in net-logo?

Tags: netlogo

Currently the size of my grid is `500` by `500`. Now i want to change the size of my grid to `400 (x-max)` by `1600 (y-max)`. The minimum point of my grid is `(0,0)`. As I pressed setup button it changes back to `500` by `500`.

In setup I wrote code of resize-world but didn't solve the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: Please provide code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

"As I pressed setup button it changes back to 500 by 500" — well, there must be something in your setup procedure that's doing that. Maybe a call to `resize-world` or `import-world`?

As for "any limitation [...]?", see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig